# Declare object from string

Tags: javascript

I want to declare 1 javascript object which its properties are generated from one sequence that was created earlier
example:

```js
var x = '"property1": "abc",
         "property2": "def",
         "property3": "xyz",
        ';
var obj = {  
  // insert content of x here
}
```

what can i do?

Comment: Make the string a JSON string and use JSON.parse(str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare

```
var x = {property1: "abc",
         property2: "def",
         property3: "xyz"};
var obj = {  
    data:x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON string here

```
var x = `{"property1": "abc",
         "property2": "def",
         "property3": "xyz"
        }`;
var obj = JSON.parse(x)
```

After reading your comments OP I think you may be after bracket notation.

You can access an object's property via dot notation

```
obj.prop = foo;
var v = obj.prop;
```

Or you can use bracket notation

```
var propName = "prop"
obj[propName] = foo;
var v = obj[propName];
```

Note this is not accessing an array.

So you could do it this way

```
var data = [["property1", "abc"],["property2","def"],["property3","xyz"]]
var obj = {};
data.forEach(pk => { obj[pk[0]] = pk[1]; });
console.log(obj.property1); // output "abc"
```

Comment: @sfblap After reading the comment on another answer you might be after bracket notation. See update on answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a string that is a valid sequence of key/value pairs that are double-quoted then you can easily make it into JSON by concatenating `'{'` and `'}'`, *after* removing any trailing comma (I notice your last property has a trailing comma). Then you can create an object by parsing that JSON. So:

```
var x = // Your string of quoted, comma-separated key/value pairs here

var obj = JSON.parse('{' + x.replace(/,\s+$/,'') + '}');
```

General note of disapproval: I don't know why you would create your properties as a string rather than just adding properties directly to an object, and in general you shouldn't hand-create JSON, and I'd like to note that a string literal enclosed by single-quotes can't have line-breaks in it so I'm hoping you just showed it that way for ease of reading.

Comment: thank you. object's propertis and its value is generated from loop and i don't know another way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` API to parse the string too.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

> The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

**Example:**

```
let y = "";
let x = ' "property1": "abc", "property2": "def", "property3": "xyz" ';
eval('y={' + x + '}');
```

**Output:**

[image]

Please note that using `eval` can be dangerous as noted in its documentation:

> eval() is a **dangerous** function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension.

Example: exposing it as a REST service to allow end-users to hit it with any 'object string' which can instead be a piece of malicious code - like downloading virus.

Comment: Shouldnt x be a string, you have it as an object literal.

Comment: @Blindman67 My mistake, I have updated the example code to match OP's original string. The output is still the same.